# Can a Simple ANN be Generative?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, generative-models

If a simple ANN was trained to predict the next step in a sequence, such as a univariate time series, can it be considered a generative model?

Answer (score 1):

A natural way to specify a generative model for sequences is $$P(x_{1\ldots t}) =  \prod_{i=1}^t P(x_i | \{x_j \text{ for } 0<j<i\})$$

So we need to specify a $P(x_i | \{x_j \text{ for } 0<j<i\})$. A reasonable choice could be something like $P(x_i | \{x_j \text{ for } 0<j<i\}) = \mathcal{N}(\mu=f(x_{i-n}, \ldots, x_{i-1}; \theta), \sigma^2=1)$ where $f$ is your NN and $\theta$ are it's parameters. There are still some details to resolve here, like what happens if $i < n$? (Maybe impute missing values with 0?). Is $\sigma^2=1$ a reasonable choice? If you used L1 loss, should we use a laplace distribution instead of normal?

Anyway, the point is that a NN itself isn't a generative model, it's just one part of the model. In simple cases like binary classification, it might be "obvious" what the model is, but often it's a bit trickier and there are some important details to take care of.